# Creating the Database Context definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

This is how to declare a DB Context according to book "Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2" , Adam Freeman.
What does this parameter mean:

```
DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options : base(options) { }
```

Trying to understand options in declaring DBContext.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace SportsStore.Models 
{
     public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
     {
         public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): 
             base(options) 
         {
         }

         public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Comment: yes, kind of confusing and unclear like much msdn documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `ApplicationDbContext` that inherits from `DbContext` like every database context have to. It represents your database object in code at which you would do CRUD-operations. Because you are inheriting you have the possibility to call the base constructor that does - in that case - the initialization. It could take none or one parameter of type `DbContextOptions<T>` or `DbContextOptions` in concrete `DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>` - that's the `base(options)` call. You could find a more detailed and maybe better explanation in this [MS doc article base(C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base)
The base class' implementation could you find on [GitHub - EntityFramework Core repository](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/8a5da5124aabb473ebf24d25094a2f9d40925c98/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L89). *(The link is referencing to the base-constructor you are calling in your code.)*

The `DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>` objects includes the configuration you may have set up before you inject it into your `ApplicationDbContext`.

More detailed from [MS docs article - Configuring DbContextOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base):

> `DbContext` must have an instance of `DbContextOptions` in order to perform any work. The `DbContextOptions` instance carries configuration information such as:
>
> - The database provider to use, typically selected by invoking a method such as `UseSqlServer` or `UseSqlite`
> - Any necessary connection string or identifier of the database instance, typically passed as an argument to the provider selection method mentioned above
> - Any provider-level optional behavior selectors, typically also chained inside the call to the provider selection method
> - Any general EF Core behavior selectors, typically chained after or before the provider selector method

In general `DbContextOptions` is a container that includes the whole database context configuration. You could define e.g. if it is a `SQL` or `in-memory` database and the change tracking behavior too. Link in question's comment already mentioned and in my answer too, the [MS doc article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions) will provide the needed  information and example.